# Iterating over IQueryable with forEach vs. calling ToList() and then doing forEach - performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I've been watching one course where the author mentioned that if you have some `IQueryable`, say:

```
var someQuery = dbContext.Table.Where(x => x.Name == "Mark");
```

and then try to iterate over the results of `someQuery` using `foreach`, it keeps the database connection open until the whole `foreach` ends, and a lot of beginner developers make this mistake and do tons of logic in the `foreach`. Instead, she recommended just calling `ToList()` up-front and then doing `foreach` on the in-memory collection.

I can't find any reference on this though, that Entity Framework keeps the database open until the `foreach` loop stops. How do I evaluate if this is true performance-wise?

Comment: I have [found that out the hard way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22530381/261050)

Comment: yes it will keep the connection open until it  encounter .toList()

Comment: The connection remains open until the enumeration of the `IQueryable` is completed. That would happen at the end of a `foreach` loop or when `.ToList()` is called. It not clear, however, that there is a performance penalty for doing it one way or another. There is definitely an issue with keeping the DB connection open for a long time - you generally want to release the connection asap.

Answer (score 7):

The `ToList()`method applied to an `IQueryable<T>` is an extension method you can see in System.core.dll with a .NET decompiler;
The method copies the "private array" if the source is an `ICollection<T>`, otherwise it executes a foreach loop from the source.

The real implementation of an an `IQueryable<T>` is `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<TResult>` and it is not  an `ICollection<T>`.

So, the `ToList()` basically copy the source using a `foreach`.

Now, it depends on the implementation, but using EF core as example, there's a [`Enumerator` class](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Query/Internal/QueryingEnumerable.cs) where you can see that the Connection (`IRelationalConnection`) is closed when the class is disposed.
According to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4111621/455531%22answer%22), and ms [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx), you should close the connection as soon as you can to release the connection and make it available in the connection pool.

> A connection pool is created for each unique connection string. When a pool is created, multiple connection objects are created and added to the pool so that the minimum pool size requirement is satisfied. Connections are added to the pool as needed, up to the maximum pool size specified (100 is the default). Connections are released back into the pool when they are closed or disposed.

so, if you are doing complex operations or executing other queries or anything else inside the foreach, the ToList is preferred.